# ¿Como se haría esta consulta en sql server utilizando Joins o sin Joins?

Tags: base-de-datos, join, sql, sql-server-2012

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Consulta: ¿Que perros han tenido rabia y de que raza?**

Hay que utilizar la tabla Animal y la tabla Ant_Clinicos (atributo enfermedades)

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y que fallos has tenido?

Comment: He intentado lo siguiente: 
SELECT Animal.Nombre, Animal.Raza FROM Animal
INNER JOIN Ant_Clinicos ON Animal.Id=Ant_Clinicos.Id
Where Ant_Clinicos.Enfermedades = 'Rabia'

Comment: De qué tabla sacas si un perro tiene rabia?

Comment: De la tabla Ant_Clinicos, atributo enfermedades

Answer (score 1):

Query con JOIN:

```
SELECT A.NOMBRE, A.ID, A.RAZA, B.ENFERMEDADES FROM ANIMAL A JOIN ANT_CLINICOS B ON A.IDANT_CLINICOS = B.ID WHERE B.ENFERMEDADES = "RABIA";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Query sin JOIN (SUBCONSULTA):

```
SELECT NOMBRE, ID, RAZA, IDANT_CLINICOS FROM ANIMAL WHERE IDANT_CLINICOS = (SELECT ID FROM ANT_CLINICOS WHERE ENFERMEDADES = "RABIA");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]